# java enums in abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, super

I know about enums in java and how they are not inheritable and are final and all that. I've been looking for this and I still haven't been able to find the alternative to what I'd like to achieve. here's the general code, as simplifed as possible:

Class **Utility**

```
public abstract class Utility {

    public Utility() {
    }

    public abstract void run() throws Exception;
}
```

Class **MyUtility1**

```
public class MyUtility1 extends Utility {

    public MyUtility1() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Class **MyUtility2**

```
public class MyUtility2 extends Utility {

    public MyUtility2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Class **Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Utility ut = null;
            if(/* something here */) {
                ut = new MyUtility1();
            } else {
                ut = new MyUtility2();
            }
            ut.run();
        } catch(MissingPropertyException e) {}
    }
}
```

Now what I need is to have a different set of constants on both MyUtility1 and MyUtility2. I'd use an enum for this:

Class **MyUtility1**

```
public class MyUtility1 extends Utility {

    public enum Properties {
        MONDAY("Monday"),
        TUESDAY("Tuesday");

        String property;

        Properties(String prop) {
            property = prop;
        }
    }

    public MyUtility1() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Class **MyUtility2**

```
public class MyUtility2 extends Utility {

    public enum Properties {
        JANUARY("January"),
        FEBRUARY("February");

        String property;

        Properties(String prop) {
            property = prop;
        }
    }

    public MyUtility2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        //do something
    }
}
```

So far, everything is ok. What I miss now is a common method, preferably in `Utility` class, to do some validation of sort, regardless which enum is called. something like:

```
protected boolean checkProperties(Properties props) throws MissingPropertyException {
    for(Property property : props.values()) {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

and on the super construtor call it like:

```
public Utility() throws MissingPropertyException {
    checkProperties(/* here comes the child.Properties */);
}
```

(yes I know the above would not compile, this is merely symbolic)

Any suggestions? If possible, leave an 'helper class' solution as last resort

Comment: That check doesn't make sense to me somehow. Leads me to the suspicion that Enum is not what you need here. What are those checks supposed to make sure?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to embed scheduling rules inside your Utility instances.  I think that's a bad idea.

A better idea would be to have all your `Utility` classes implement `Runnable` or `Callable`.  Give those to scheduled `Executor` instances that would carry the rules.

Separate what's done from when it's done.  You might want to change the schedule without having to modify the `Utility` instances.  Externalizing that logic and making it configurable will make it easy.

Comment: Im not sure I understood what you meant with 'scheduling rules' or even the 'when its done' part. if its the actual enum values thats confusing, then just rename them to AUDI("audi"), VOLVO("volvo") or even RED("red"), GREEN("green").. they're really unimportant...

the general idea here is that the ut.run() doesn't get called when it fails to construct an Utility object, because one of the enum properties was not found somewhere, and the properties depend on the child Utility class...

and the idea that an enum is "required" is because these enum values could then be used in other places

Comment: That was my first thought on `Utility` class : "Looks like a Runnable" ...

Comment: Forget enum.  You have month, day, etc in those enums (better defined elsewhere, by the way).  They don't depend on a Utility class; it's the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you want to use generics.

Lets image that you extract your properties to 'Day' and 'Month' enum, your Utility1 and Utility2 class seems to be kind of 'Utility' and 'Utility'

To complete your samples this would be something like :

**Utility.java**

```
public abstract class Utility<T> {
    protected Utility(T prop) throws Exception {
        checkProperties(prop);
    }
    public abstract void run() throws Exception;
    public abstract void checkProperties(T prop) throws Exception;
}
```

**Utility1.java**

```
public class Utility1 extends Utility<Day> {
    public Utility1(Day day) throws Exception {
        super(day);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception { }
    @Override
    public void checkProperties(Day prop) throws Exception { }
}
```

**Utility2.java**

```
public class Utility2 extends Utility<Month> {
    public Utility2(Month month) throws Exception {
        super(month);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception { }
    @Override
    public void checkProperties(Month prop) throws Exception { }
}
```

**Day.java**

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY;
}
```

**Month.java**

```
public enum Month implements IProperties {
    JANUARY, FEBRUARY;
}
```

You could additionnaly have your enums implement an interface (say IProperties) and make Utility to enforce stronger typing

Comment: i wanted to avoid replicating code, since checkProperties does the exact same thing for any Utility instance... the only thing that varies in the entire thing are the actual values of the 'property' attribute in each enum constant

Answer (score 0):

Convert checkProperties to abstract to be implemented by the classes.

```
 protected abstract boolean checkProperties() throws MissingPropertyException;
```

Now implement the checkProperties in both the classes, as per requirement. If the same method is used to check, create it in utility class.

Alternatively change

```
   protected boolean checkProperties(Class<? extends Enum> clazz) throws MissingPropertyException {
           Enum[] enum =  clazz.getEnumConstants(); //Do required validation here
}
```

and in the constructor call appropriate Properties.class

```
public MyUtility2() {
   super(Properties.class)    
}


public Utility(Class<? extends Enum> clazz) throws MissingPropertyException {
    checkProperties(clazz);
}
```

as `for(Property property : props.values()) { //Cannot work for any property.`

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to make class `Utility` generic like this :

```
public abstract class Utility<T extends Enum<?>> {

     T[] properties
     public Utility() {
         checkProperties();
     }
     protected void checkProperties() throws MissingPropertyException;
     public abstract void run() throws Exception;
}
```

then define MyUtility1 like this :

```
class MyUtility1 extends Utility<MyProperties1> { //class body }
```

And so on for MyUtility2, note that on main , variable ut should be declared `Utility<?>` .
This solution has shortcomings, for example if you have a function in `Utility` that takes T as paramater and you want it to be polymorphic it wouldn't work.

Another suggestion is to make properties `Enum<?>[]` instead of `T[]`, Enum is an abstract class so there are some problems with this, first you need to cast whenever you want to deal with the real type, like in `checkProperties` for example.

Second any enum can be put in `properties` so you have to make some function `addProperty` and this function must validate the type of the property passed in.

I think the best solution is to leave enums out of inheritance :) .